# How to convert a react native image uri into binary file

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo-image-picker to pick image from a device but it is returning image uri. I want to send that image as a binary file to my api. Image uri is not working for me in the backend. Can anyone please help me out i am stuck in this problem for days.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways you can solve this problem:

**1. Set  `base64`  to `true`  for launch media library method options**

```js
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    allowsEditing: true,
    aspect: [4, 4],
    quality: 1,
    base64:true
  });
```

Then upload image base64 data

**2. Fetch image binary data preferably in BLOB format.**

```js
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
  };
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open("GET", [PATH_TO_LOCAL_FILE_HERE], true);
  xhr.send(null);
});

// Your logic to upload `blob` to a backend server or cloud provider

// We're done with the blob, close and release it
blob.close();
```